# TypeError: bad operand type for unary +: 'str' when I give the command

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, discord, discord.py

I am trying to run the command

```
!en L BTC 19000 15000 20000
```

A month ago it worked, but now it doesn't. I don't know what happened. Here's the relevant code:

```
async def en(ctx):
    if (ctx.author.id == 573284477158162433 or ctx.author.id == 244240895627624448):
        global channels, message
        x = ctx.message.content
        #command = (''.join(x).split())
        message = ""
        print(len(x))
        if(x[4]=="L"):
            message = "**Type: Long **"+"\n **Ticker: **"+ x[6:9] + "\n  **Entry Price:** " + x[10:15] + "\n **Take Profit: **" + x[16:21]  
            +"\n **Stop Loss: ** " + x[22:len(x)]
            #+ " \n **Comments:** " + x[27:len(x)]
            print(message)
        elif(x[4]=="S"):
            message = "**Type: Short **"+"\n **Ticker: **"+x[6:9] + "\n  **Entry Price:** " + x[10:14] + "\n **Take Profit: **" + x[15:21]
            print(message)
```

Here's the error I'm getting:

> TypeError: bad operand type for unary +: 'str'

Comment: You're missing a line continuation character \ on this line: `message = "**Type: Long **"+"\n **Ticker: **"+ x[6:9] + "\n  **Entry Price:** " + x[10:15] + "\n **Take Profit: **" + x[16:21]` (or just merge the two lines together)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what your problem is exactly, however, I would suggest that you used a format string. This can be accomplished by adding an 'f' in front of your 'message' string.

```
async def en(ctx):
    if (ctx.author.id == 573284477158162433 or ctx.author.id == 244240895627624448):
        global channels, message
        x = ctx.message.content
        #command = (''.join(x).split())
        message = ""
        print(len(x))
        if(x[4]=="L"):
            message = f"**Type: Long **\n **Ticker: ** {x[6:9]}\n  **Entry Price:** {x[10:15]}\n **Take Profit: ** {x[16:21]}  
            \n **Stop Loss: ** {x[22:len(x)]}"
            #+ " \n **Comments:** " + x[27:len(x)]
            print(message)
        elif(x[4]=="S"):
            message = f"**Type: Short **\n **Ticker: ** {x[6:9]}\n  **Entry Price:** {x[10:14]}\n **Take Profit: ** {x[15:21]}"
            print(message)
```

I would also suggest that you used 'slash' commands since it's a more elegant way of using commands. You can see how to implement 'slash' commands [here](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/v2.0.1/examples/app_commands/basic.py).